Implementing Addressable for android package
We are currently trying to implement addressable for PAD but face a issue with asset packing.
We are following this Manual : https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables.android@1.0/manual/install.html
We have apply every step this manual mentions but the problem we are getting is for OnDemand asset pack. The OnDemand asset pack is also being added to the base module of the .aab. The manual says that if its is OnDemand then it will be installed and loading at runtime. but after making the aab  the bundle made is inside the base module itself.
would really appreciate any kind of help?
Thank you in advance.
Tired to assign it for asset pack but it still doesn't work.
